# Comoving and physical momentum in a Friedmann universe

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, cosmology, momentum, fourier-transform

It is most probably a very basic question, but I'm a bit stuck with it. Let us consider a spatially flat Friedmann universe with the usual metric

$$ds^2=dt^2-a^2(t)\left(dr^2+r^2d\vartheta^2+r^2\sin^2(\vartheta)d\varphi^2\right)$$

where $dl^2$ is just the line element of the equal time hypersurface. Let us also consider a scalar quantum field $\Phi(x)$ living in the Friedmann spacetime,

$$\Phi(x)=\int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}\left(\hat{a}_kv_k(t)e^{-ikx}+\hat{a}^\dagger_kv^*_k(t)e^{ikx}\right)$$

where $v_k$ are the mode functions in the given case. Then, if $x=(t,\vec{r}(r,\vartheta,\varphi))$ is the four vector in comoving coordinates, $k$ is the conjugate momentum which I would understand as the comoving momentum.

Now, my question is, how to get the physical momentum $p$? Usually people define it as

$$p=a^{-1}(t)k$$

See for example (2.15) on page 10 in http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0201158v2

If I consider a particle far away in comoving distance $r=const$ following the Hubble flow, I'd expect it to have comoving momentum zero. But then, according to the above definition of physical momentum, the physical momentum itself is also zero! On the other hand, I don't see why a particle, which follows the Hubble flow and therefore has no peculiar velocity, should have a non-zero comoving momentum.

I have the impression that my intuition on Fourier transform fails in this case, could anybody please explain where my mistake is?

Thanks in advance!